# Memory leak using dataWithContentsOfURL in a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, block

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS 5.5/6.1.6 .

I am using a background thread to load large quantities of jpg from a server to iOS devices.

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^
               {
                   // get the array of filenames to download
                   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webPath];
                   NSArray* theArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
                   if( theArray )
                   {
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           // disable screen buttons
                           [self setButtons:false];
                       });

                       [self loadImagesFromList:theArray sourceBundle:bundlePath destBundle:localBundlePath manager:manager];

                       if (!stopFlag) {
                           // if no memory error has occurred
                           NSLog(@"calling refresh after load_images");
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                               [self refresh];
                           });
                       }
                       theArray = nil;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Error loading bundle");
                   }
               });
```

The background method:

```
-(void)loadImagesFromList:(NSArray *)theArray
             sourceBundle:(NSString *)bundlePath
               destBundle:(NSString *)localBundlePath
                  manager:(NSFileManager *)manager {

    // initialize the progress and activity indicator
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.activityIndictor startAnimating];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [self.progressIndictor setProgress:0 animated:NO];
    });

    NSURL *url;
    NSString *srcFile;
    NSString *destFile;
    NSError *error = nil;

    int counter = 0;
    float prog = 0;
    float increment = 1.0 / [theArray count];
    float stepSize = [theArray count] / 10;

    for (NSString *file in theArray)
    {
        if (stopFlag) {
            NSLog(@"I see stopFlag = true, counter = %d, prog = %f", counter, prog);
            return;
        }
        srcFile = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        destFile = [localBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

        counter += 1;
        prog += increment;
        if (counter == stepSize) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.progressIndictor.progress = prog;
            });
            counter = 0;
        }

        // only download if file isn't already here
        BOOL fileExists = [manager fileExistsAtPath:destFile]; // check if we already have it
        if (!fileExists) {
            // jpg or folder check
            if ([[destFile pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
                url = [NSURL URLWithString:srcFile];
                data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                             options:0
                                               error:&error];

                [data writeToFile:destFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                data = nil;
            } else {
                [manager createDirectoryAtPath:destFile withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the files exist, the loop zips through the array and exits back to the main thread ok.
If any files are missing, the download/write part seems to chew up the RAM and cause low memory warning to trigger.  It takes several thousand files to do it.

I've tried declaring the variables outside the loop, and even doing the whole thing in the main thread to test if that was causing the leak. 
I tried using the alternate dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error call.
I tried Instruments, but it is really slow and crashes often.  Before crashing, it does show allocation going up, up, up slowly.

After several days on this, I'm stumped.

Comment: Your title describes this as a "leak", but I was wondering if you have some reason to characterize it as a leak, as opposed to just a fact that you have a lot of very large autorelease objects that won't be deallocated until the autorelease pool is drained. My answer below assumes the latter is true, but if you have some evidence of a genuine leak, let us know, but I don't see anything there that would leak. The main issue appears to be that the autorelease pool isn't getting drained frequently enough.

Comment: After reading your answer I guess you're right. I assumed the objects were being released, so there would be no increase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I'd suggest is using an `@autoreleasepool` to control the peak amount of memory consumed. Right now, you're downloading the contents into the `NSData` as an autorelease object, and when done, you're `nil`-ing that variable, which simple flags it to be deallocated once the autorelease pool is drained (which will not happen until `loadImagesFromList` is done). By (a) moving the variable declarations inside the `for` loop; and (b) wrapping this in an `@autoreleasepool`, your memory will be deallocated as the individual downloads finish.

```
-(void)loadImagesFromList:(NSArray *)theArray
             sourceBundle:(NSString *)bundlePath
               destBundle:(NSString *)localBundlePath
                  manager:(NSFileManager *)manager {

    // initialize the progress and activity indicator
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // your UI update here
    });

    int counter = 0;
    float prog = 0;
    float increment = 1.0 / [theArray count];
    float stepSize = [theArray count] / 10;

    for (NSString *file in theArray)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            if (stopFlag) {
                NSLog(@"I see stopFlag = true, counter = %d, prog = %f", counter, prog);
                return;
            }

            NSString *srcFile = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            NSString *destFile = [localBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

            counter += 1;
            prog += increment;
            if (counter == stepSize) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.progressIndictor.progress = prog;
                });
                counter = 0;
            }

            // only download if file isn't already here
            BOOL fileExists = [manager fileExistsAtPath:destFile]; // check if we already have it
            if (!fileExists) {
                NSError *error = nil;

                // jpg or folder check
                if ([[destFile pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:srcFile];
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:&error];

                    [data writeToFile:destFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                } else {
                    [manager createDirectoryAtPath:destFile withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't using `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:...]` instead of `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...]` also solve this problem?

Comment: "and when done, you're nil-ing that variable" he's not `nil`-ing anything; it's just going out of scope

Comment: newacct, yes, if he used `initWithContentsOfURL` that makes it non-autorelease object, which would greatly diminish the need for a pool, but he does have other autorelease objects, and by using a manual pool, it eliminates the need to worry about which are autorelease and which are not. But you're right, if he was scrupulous about not using autorelease objects, then the manual pool would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refactor this code to use `NSOperationQueue`. This addresses the peak memory issue, but also let's you enjoy a degree of concurrency. Because iOS only allows 4-5 concurrent requests anyway, you want to limit the maximum number of concurrent operations to a reasonable number, and this mitigates network timeout risks if trying to run too many concurrent requests. (This `maxConcurrentOperationCount` feature is the main reason I suggest using operation queues.)

Anyway, that might look like:

```
-(void)loadImagesFromList:(NSArray *)theArray
             sourceBundle:(NSString *)bundlePath
               destBundle:(NSString *)localBundlePath
                  manager:(NSFileManager *)manager {

    // initialize the progress and activity indicator
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // your UI update here
    }];

    int   __block counter = 0;
    float __block prog = 0;
    float increment = 1.0 / [theArray count];
    float stepSize = [theArray count] / 10;

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

    for (NSString *file in theArray)
    {
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if (stopFlag) {
                NSLog(@"I see stopFlag = true, counter = %d, prog = %f", counter, prog);
                return;
            }

            NSString *srcFile = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            NSString *destFile = [localBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                counter += 1;
                prog += increment;
                if (counter == stepSize) {
                    self.progressIndictor.progress = prog;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }];

            // only download if file isn't already here
            BOOL fileExists = [manager fileExistsAtPath:destFile]; // check if we already have it
            if (!fileExists) {
                NSError *error = nil;

                // jpg or folder check
                if ([[destFile pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:srcFile];
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:&error];

                    [data writeToFile:destFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                } else {
                    [manager createDirectoryAtPath:destFile withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

There are other refinements I might suggest (e.g. implementing cancelation logic rather than looking at `stopFlag`), but I was trying to minimize the code changes. I'm just taking advantage of the fact that one can easily replace `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{ ... });
```

with `NSOperationQueue` method `addOperationWithBlock`:

```
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{ ... }];
```

But now we can use a concurrent `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 4 or 5, and you suddenly enjoy a nice, constrained degree of concurrency. You may find that this is observably faster than downloading files sequentially.